# Touchpad doesn't work after logging in

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

The touchpad of my laptop fails to work soon after I login to Ubuntu. I've gone through several threads in forums regarding the same matter and have tried out:

> `gconftool -set boolean ... command`

I've even tried to reboot the system in recovery mode. I've unchecked the System -> Preferences -> Enable touchpad while key type and restarted as well.

None of the above methods which did work for few seem to work for me. Please help me. How can I fix the touchpad issue in Ubuntu 11.10 without a reinstall?

I am using 64 bit Oneiric, on an Dell Inspiron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue, my touchpad was working in a super basic (move and click only) mode.

After reading all the comments on https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/550625/ I got it to work by installing Seth's psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all.deb from comment #492:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/linux/+bug/550625/comments/492

**Now I have:**

- touchpad preferences in system settings
- two finger vertical and horizontal scroll
- tow finger right-click

*My touchpad is "AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad".*

**Find out your touchpad brand running:**

```
xinput list
```

**good luck!**

Luciano

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this happen sporadically  on a Dell latop. While disabling the "Disable touchpad while typing" seemed to help, the best solution here was to set this also.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse active false
```

An active bug on
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/868400

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I found a blog that had a command that actually fixed the issue
synclient TouchpadOff=0

I ran the command as sudo synclient TouchpadOff=0, and it worked, exactly a

Answer (score 0):

I've tried running in a terminal `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse` and it worked.