# Problems with 12.10. Can't find menu.lst in /boot/grub

Tags: 12.10, grub2, reboot

I have Asus 1225N and I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 but I have 2 major problems:

1. Sometimes when I restart the system after boot my touchpad and keyboard don't work and I must reset 3 or 4 times
2. When the system boot nothing, shows only purple screen without Ubuntu logo and sometimes  stucks at this page and I must reboot the system 2 or 3 times.

I didn't find `menu.lst` in `/boot/grub`. Is this problem occurred for missing `menu.lst`?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not because of that. Ubuntu 12.10 uses GRUB2, which according to [this wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), doesn't use `menu.lst` anymore.

As for your touchpad problem, have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/72364/83046) question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should mix up many questions into one. If people search for questions by different criteria they might not find yours.

Anyway, I can only say something definite about the menu.lst issue. Ubuntu switched a while ago to the Grub2 bootloader (from legacy grub). There is a new and very different configuration mechanism, no more menu.lst.
For details see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

I'm not sure about your other problems, they might be hardware compatibility issues. You should be able to find more information in the System log in /var/log/syslog 
Although it is not so easy to interpret this information, depending on you experience with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Asus 1225B and had the same touchpad/keybpoard unresponsive problem on 12.04 but was able to fix it. Take a look at this Launchpad Bug [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1014240/comments/16) (bug is [#1014240](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1014240)). It is a kernel related issue, and can be fixed by booting with a different/non-default boot option by changing `grub`'s defaults.

- Basically, you need to edit (as root) `/etc/default/grub` by adding the following options to the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:
  `"i8042.reset i8042.nomux"`
- By default, the file should already have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
- So basically you'll change that line to say:

  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.reset i8042.nomux"`
- Save the file.

Don't forget to execue `sudo update-grub` after. Reboot to test.